sampling importance resampling -- what is the formula of variance?
I'm recently looking into SIR, I'm not very familiar with probability. Here it mentioned that if the variance of the sum approaches 0, then the output PDF approaches the target PDF, I wonder what is the formula of the variance? And in what case, the sum will approach 0? Thanks in advance for any answer! 

There is  no closed form expression due to the renormalisattion by the sum of the IS weights...

@Xi'an So what is the case where we will get 0 variance? Like if we have a large number of samples, and the variance is close to 0, what kind of property will they have?
